# How to keep image 100% width of view port with fixed aspect ration 16/9

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I have researched the subject quite a lot and the solution – which must work with a parallax effect (using GSscrolltrigger) – seems a bit complicated to me (because I have to change the height of the parent div based on @media css.  In my case, the img (16/9 ratio) must be in the child div inside a bootstrap fluid container div.

Is there a way to do that dynamically or another better and simpler approach?

```
<div class="container-fluid parallax-main d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <div class="parallax-image" style="background: url('pathToImage') no-repeat; background-size:cover;"></div>
    <div class="parallax-overlay">...</div>
</div>

.parallax-main {
  height: 50vmin;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.parallax-image { 
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}
.parallax-overlay {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1140px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .parallax-main { height: 55vmin; }  
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
  .parallax-main { height: 60vmin; }  
}

@media (min-width:1100px) { 
  .parallax-main { height: 70vmin; }
}

@media (min-width:1200px) { 
  .parallax-main { height: 80vmin; }
}

@media (min-width:1200px) { 
  .parallax-main { height: 90vmin; }
}

@media (min-width:1400px) { 
  .parallax-main { height: 100vmin; }
}
```

Comment: User `height: auto` and width: 100%; this will maintain the aspect ratio of the image on resizing

Comment: @TeckFreak if I only change the class parallpax-image to height:auto, the image is not visible.  So that only does not work.

Comment: You have to use both the values.

Answer (score 0):

Try `width: 100vw` on `.parallax-image`

Comment: That alone does not work either.  I found a solution that does not require any @media css.  On parallax-main width: 98.7vw & height: 46vw; /* normally 56.25 % of viewport width to keep 16:9 ratio - trick is to make it 20% smaller so the parallax effect is more visible */ then on parallax-image, width: 100%;
  height: 120%; /* this must be 20% taller to allow parallax effect - work in conjonction with parent div above */ What is very strange is that if the width of the parallax image is 100vw, I get an horizontal scroll bar... 98.7 is the max giving no scroll bar!
  width: 98.7vw;